# Set Identity as (11 - 2) in sql table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, identity

I have a issue,

I want to set the `ID` column, where the `ID` should start from `11-2` then it should auto- increment by 1 like

11-3, 11-4.

I am using `sql-server 2008 R2`. Please help

Comment: Will the prefix always be `11-` or will it eventually turn into `12-`, `13-`, etc..?

Comment: @John: For now, let say it will be always `11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `IDENTITY` column for the incrementing ID value, then prefix it with `11-` as a computed column.

```
CREATE TABLE [Table2]
    (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
    ID_pretty AS ('11-' + CAST(ID AS nvarchar))
    CONSTRAINT pk_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID))
GO
```

Comment: how to set ID here  as primary key ?

Comment: getting error as `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '11-' to data type int.`

Comment: I added two more columns to it, one is `varchar` and another one is `int`. When I run the select query, I got the above mentioned error

Comment: `Select * from Tablename` is my simple query

Comment: @Nadeem Answer updated - I forgot to `CAST` the int as a varchar.